# How to handle Fault state on WCF? (hosting in Windows service)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, event-handling

I'm hosting WCF as Widnows Service but I have a problem with handling Faulted state of WCF channel. Faulted event on ServiceHost never rise up.

Hosting application:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCF_FaultTest.Service1));
        _serviceHost.Faulted += _serviceHost_Faulted;
        _serviceHost.Open();
    }

    void _serviceHost_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // never raise up..
    }
```

Faulted state I try to simulate like this:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetFault()
    {
        throw new Exception("Should went to fault..");
    }
```

Do I using it correctly? Thank you.

Comment: thanks, but I already try this(in real implementation). With custom IErrorHandler problem remain the same.  Every Exception is correcty processed in HandleError, but Faulted event on ServiceHost still wont raise.. ( I would like to abort and recreate ServiceHost when fault)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using more than one CommunicationObject. When you throw the exception in your service implementation the channel is faulted, but the host it is not. **The ServiceHost.Faulted event does not apply in this case.**

One thing to remember is that once a CommunicationObject enters the faulted state, it can no longer be used. The only thing to do with a faulted CommunicationObject is to close/abort. After your service throws the exception, if you create a new channel you can still call the service. Therefore the service is not faulted.

From an architecture point of view, a service host event is not the "right" place to implement error handling. In general you want error processing to be part of the service configuration. For example error handling in a ServiceHost event doesn't easily move to IIS hosting. Your comment makes it sound like IErrorHandler didn't meet your requirements. What requirement are you trying to implement?

Comment: Ernie, my problem is that I don't know when CommunicationObject enters the faulted state.

In my mind I was thinking, that in ServiceHost.Faulted event can be do this:
_serviceHost.Abort();
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCF_FaultTest.Service1));
_serviceHost.Open();

Comment: In my point of view, IErrorHandler is great place for logging exceptions, etc.. But I would like to "detect" when channel enters the faulted state and then I like to call Abort() a open a new instace of my WCF Service.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that isn't a problem. When the channel is faulted, the client should open a new channel. But when the channel is faulted, the servicehost is unaffected and should do nothing.

Comment: Even when InstanceContextMode is set to Single, ConcurrencyMode also Single?

Comment: Yes. (... and then the mandatory number of characters for a comment)